# What to do to make GWT product Strict CSP Comapatible?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, content-security-policy

I have made a web app in gwt, CSP Mitigator is saying that, I have many eval statements and javascript uri's in js loaded, so my project is not Strict CSP Compatible .

But problem in my case is that, I write code in java and gwwt make js for me.

I also asked gwt community, but they says that in next release of gwt, csp compliance will be covered.

But till then, Do anyone knows, how can I solve this vulnerability .

Comment: As far as I can tell, all of those CSP patches are merged except one (which won't matter to you if you don't use touch events) - you could use the nightly build until the 2.8.2 release comes out?

Comment: Also, hard to help without a list of those violations. In the mean time, don't use strict CSP, enable unsafe-inline scripts (I thought we got rid of evals in 2.7 or 2.8, would be interested in knowing where they come from)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Release Of gwt 2.8.2 has come which is csp compliance .

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely out of box, just improved CSP support in gwt-2.8.2.

For instance GWT compiled js includes data URLs such as data:image/gif;base64.. and will violate img-src 'self';

It is awkward including such URLs in CSP. More worse using img-src 'self' data:; as hackers can inject anything in data scheme.

This can be turned off in module gwt.xml. Disable the use of data: URLs

`<set-property name="ClientBundle.enableInlining" value="false" />`

There are also pending CSP issues where GWT code base still uses eval that require unsafe-eval in CSP declarations.

> Additionally, this is an issue since it violates CSP, as eval isn't
>   particularly safe, and some sites would like to forbid its use to
>   further protect their data and their users.

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9578